# In Python, searching a text file for multiple words and printing the corresponding lines

Tags: python, string, list, file, search

I have a list of sentences I would like to search. I want to print the lines that contain my search words. This code works:

```
fruit_list = open('fruitlist.txt')
for line in fruit_list:
    if 'apple' in line or 'banana' in line or 'orange' in line:
        print (line)
```

But this can be pretty tedious; especially if I want my list of search words to be longer.  I would like to make a list of search words and use that to search the document and print the line.

```
search_words=['apple','banana','orange','lemon']
for line in fruit_list:
    if item in search_words in line:
        print (line)
```

This code doesn't work because "item" isn't defined. Anyway I could get this done? I'm a newbie with python.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
fruit_list = open('fruitlist.txt')

search_words = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'lemon']

for line in fruit_list:
    if any(word in line for word in search_words):
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# with Regular Expression 
import re

fruit_list = open('test.txt')
search_words = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'lemon']

patten = re.compile("(.*(apple|banana|orange|lemon)(.*))")

for i in [re.search(patten,line).groups() for line  in      fruit_list  if re.search(patten,line) != None]: print(i)
```