# Check for existence of at least one string in a list

Tags: python

I have code that checks whether there is at least one of the modal verbs in my `word_list`.

```
with open('Requirements_good.txt') as myfile:
    word_list=[word for line in myfile for word in line.split()]


with open('Badwords_modalverbs.txt') as file:
    modalv = 0
    for word in file.readlines():
        if word.strip() in word_list:
            modalv = 1
    if modalv == 1:
        print ("one of the words found")
```

But there must be an easier, more elegant way to solve this. What is the quickest way to check it?

And how would one check for the opposit?: print anything if none of the words are found

Comment: `max([word.strip() in word_list for work in open('Badwords_modalverbs.txt').readlines()])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, searching a text file for multiple words and printing the corresponding lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51297805/in-python-searching-a-text-file-for-multiple-words-and-printing-the-correspondi)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, make `word_list` a set instead of a list, so that it's efficient to test membership of it. Then, you can use the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function:

```py
with open('Requirements_good.txt') as myfile:
    # set comprehension instead of list comprehension
    word_set = {word for line in myfile for word in line.split()}

with open('Badwords_modalverbs.txt') as file:
    if any(word.strip() in word_set for word in file):
        print("one of the words found")
```

This is more efficient because you're no longer searching a list to test membership, but also the `any` function won't keep searching after it finds one match. The [`file.readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) function is also unnecessary here; `for word in file` iterates over the lines without creating a list first.

Comment: How whould I do it, if I want to check for the opposit?
- print sth if none of the words are found?

Comment: `if not any(...):`